# Using the BrowsableAPIRenderer in debug=False mode

Tags: templates, django-rest-framework

When I use the BrowsableAPIRenderer with debug=False I get a 500 error

Is there any way to use the BrowsableAPIRenderer in production mode or similar built-in templates other than JSONRenderer